Positioning a button over an image in Interactive Viewer in Flutter
I want to put buttons over an image in Interactive Viewer on specific positions relative to the image. I'm using Stack and constrained: true. I don't know how to stick the buttons to coordinates of the image. When I zoom the image or change the proportions of the viewport, the buttons are not fixed to their positions corresponding to the image.
I've tried to position them using percentages of MediaQuery and wrapping everything into a LayoutBuilder, but none of it is working.
Here's my code:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewPage()),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget> [
                  Positioned(child: Image.asset(""),)
                  Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text(""),
                    ),
                  )
                ] 
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


You can use a LayoutBuilder which helps in adapting to different screen sizes and zoom levels. And then use a Stack in combination with a Positioned button to place it relative to your image.
...
child: InteractiveViewer(
    child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
            // Dummy image size, replace with actual image dimensions or use an image widget with a listener.
            double imageWidth = 600; // Replace with actual image width
            double imageHeight = 400; // Replace with actual image height

            double buttonWidth = constraints.maxWidth * 0.1;
            double buttonHeight = constraints.maxHeight * 0.1;

            double buttonX = imageWidth * 0.3;
            double buttonY = imageHeight * 0.3;

            return Stack(
              children: [
                // Your image widget here
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "",
                    width: imageWidth,
                    height: imageHeight,
                  ),
                ),
                // Positioned button
                Positioned(
                  left: buttonX - (buttonWidth / 2),
                  top: buttonY - (buttonHeight / 2),
                  width: buttonWidth,
                  height: buttonHeight,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text("Button"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
...

